# Why doesn't NSString support objectAtIndexedSubscript and how to work around?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I would like to be able to write things like:

```
NSString *foo = ...;
unichar c = foo[i];
```

but oddly, `NSString` doesn't support array indexing via `objectAtIndexedSubscript`. Why doesn't it?

To work around this, would it be sensible to implement a category (e.g., `NSString+Indexing`) to extend `NSString`?

Comment: But unichar is not an object.

Comment: Have you looked at the NSString class reference? What do you say to `unichar c = [string characterAtIndex]`?

Answer (score 4):

Add a category on NSString with the method:

```
-(id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    if(idx >= self.length)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    return @([self characterAtIndex:idx]);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
unichar c = [foo[i] unsignedShortValue]
```

Note that c will be 0 both when the character is the null character, or index is out of bounds.

Comment: But is that a sensible solution? (the OP's question)

Comment: This is not what OP is asking

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh... Duh... Silly me, why didn't I realize that?... A `unichar` is not an Objective-C object; therefore, `objectAtIndexedSubscript` doesn't make sense for `NSString`. That's why it doesn't support it...and can't.

Comment: I think it's a good solution. It's more useful to get the NSNumber object than a unichar in many cases. Use it like this: NSNumber *charNumber = myArray[i]; Then you can compare the charNumber object or store it in an array or dictionary. Only get the unichar when you really need it.